# Django: TypeError - argument of type 'QuerySet' is not iterable

Tags: python, django

So this error is very cryptic, how can it be that a `Queryset` object, even if empty, is not iterable?

This is the rare error I'm seeing:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'QuerySet' is not iterable
```

And this is the code producing this error:

```
artist_object = Artist.objects.get(id=id)
artist_release_groups = artist_object.release_groups.all()
if rg not in artist_release_groups: # this is the line where the error is  happening
    artist_object.release_groups.add(rg)
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but this is happening in a celery task and the error is being reported in Sentry (an exception reporting service).

Traceback that I have:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'QuerySet' is not iterable
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "core/tasks.py", line 234, in refresh_artist_task
    get_apple_release_groups_for_artist(applemusic_id)
  File "celery/local.py", line 191, in __call__
    return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 642, in __protected_call__
    return orig(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "celery/app/task.py", line 375, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "core/tasks.py", line 147, in get_apple_release_groups_for_artist
    if rg not in artist_release_groups:
```

**Update:** not sure, but I think this related to [this issue on the Django forums](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26600). (see last three replies)

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Which line is this happening on?

Comment: @DanielRoseman hey Daniel - I attached what I have.

Comment: you want to check if one result is there, you can use `exists()` instead.. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#exists

Comment: What is `rg` and `exclude` won't help in this case eh?

Comment: @DanielM - no, I want to check if `rg`, a `release_group`, is in an `artist`'s release groups queryset.

Comment: @zerohedge Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a filter in the if.
instead of: 

`if rg not in artist_release_groups:
    artist_object.release_groups.add(rg)`

use

```
artist_release_groups_query = artist_object.release_groups.filter(id=rg.id)
if not artist_rease_groups_query.exists():
    # add the rest
```

Comment: what is the rationale behind this?

Comment: I'm asking about the rationale for 2 reasons: 1) to ask if you know why is `in` not work these rare cases 2) using `exists` means that I'm going to be pinging the database for every check, as opposed to storing `artist_object.release_groups.all()` once and then checking in that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, using the "in" operator I got the error message "QuerySet is not iterable", after changing my code to the "exists" version, I realize that I forgot a migration (the error message changed to "table does not exist"). Didn't try, but I guess that if I revert the change, now that the migration was applied, no error will be raised.

My conclusion: The "in" operator works, but is harder to debug in rare situations (when a migration is missing, for example), then, it's better to use the uglier "exists" version.